# json_encode removes "/" slashes

Tags: php, json, ajax

when i send this code trough json_encode:

```
$destino = base_url().'proprietarios/visualiza/'.$item->PR_CODIGO;
$coluna1 .= '<a href="#null" class="btn btn-default float-left sem-permissao '.$menu_permissao['proprietarios'].'" onclick="modal_abre(\"'.$destino.'\",\"modal-wide\");">
                    <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
                  </a>';
```

It turn's out that onclick variable $destino stay's like this:
proprietarios visualiza 10

Json_encode is removing slashes? How to keep them?

**EDITED
This is the full code:

```
$data = array();
    $no = $_POST['start'];
    foreach ($resultados as $resultado) {
        $row = array();
        $coluna1 = '';
        if($item->PR_EXIBIR=='I'){//Se está inativo, pode deletar ou reativar
            if($menu_permissao['proprietarios_deleta']){
                $coluna1 = '<a href="#null" class="btn btn-default float-left sem-permissao '.$menu_permissao['proprietarios_deleta'].'" data-href="javascript:registro_deleta(\"PROPRIETARIOS\",\"CC\",\"$item->PR_CODIGO\");" data-btn-ok-label="Deletar" data-toggle="confirmation" >
                    <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                  </a>';
            }else{
                $coluna1 = '<a href="#null" class="btn btn-default float-left sem-permissao '.$menu_permissao['proprietarios_deleta'].'" > 
                    <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                  </a>';
            }
            //Pode reativar
            if($menu_permissao['proprietarios_altera']){
                $coluna1 .='<a href="#null" class="btn btn-default float-left sem-permissao '.$menu_permissao['proprietarios_deleta'].'" data-href="javascript:registro_ativa(\"PROPRIETARIOS\",\"CC\",\"'.$item->PR_CODIGO.'\");" data-btn-ok-label="Reativar" data-toggle="confirmation">
                <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i>
              </a>';
            }else{
                $coluna1 .='<a href="#null" class="btn btn-default float-left sem-permissao">
                <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i>
              </a>';
            }
        }else{
            //Pode inativar?
            if($menu_permissao['proprietarios_deleta']){
                $coluna1 .='<a href="#null" class="btn btn-default float-left sem-permissao '.$menu_permissao['proprietarios_deleta'].' data-href="javascript:registro_inativa(\"PROPRIETARIOS\",\"CC\",\"'.$item->PR_CODIGO.'\");" data-btn-ok-label="Inativar" data-toggle="confirmation" >
                <i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i>
                </a>';
            }else{
                $coluna1 .='<a href="#null" class="btn btn-default float-left sem-permissao '.$menu_permissao['proprietarios_deleta'].'" >
                <i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i>
                </a>';
            }
        }

        //Agora alteração
        $destino = base_url().'proprietarios/altera/'.$item->PR_CODIGO;
        if($menu_permissao['proprietarios_altera']){
            $coluna1 .='<a href="#null" class="btn btn-default float-left sem-permissao '.$menu_permissao['proprietarios_altera'].'" onclick="modal_abre(\"'.$destino.'\", \"modal-wide\");">
                <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
              </a>';
        }else{
            $coluna1 .='<a href="#null" class="btn btn-default float-left sem-permissao '.$menu_permissao['proprietarios_altera'].'">
                <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
              </a>';
        }

        $destino = base_url().'proprietarios/visualiza/'.$item->PR_CODIGO;
        $coluna1 .= '<a href="#null" class="btn btn-default float-left sem-permissao '.$menu_permissao['proprietarios'].'" onclick="modal_abre(\"'.$destino.'\",\"modal-wide\");">
                <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
              </a>';
        $destino = base_url().'funcoes/historico_visualiza/PROPRIETARIOSCONTATOS/'.$item->PR_CODIGO;
        $coluna1 .= '<a href="#null" class="btn btn-default float-left" onclick="modal_abre(\"'.$destino.'\",\"modal-wide\");">
              <i class="fa fa-book"></i>
            </a>';

        $coluna1 .= $resultado->PR_CODIGO;
        $row[] = $coluna1;
        $row[] = $resultado->PR_NOME;
        $row[] = $resultado->PR_CODIGO;

        $data[] = $row;
    }


    //echo $this->db->last_query();
    //echo var_dump($this->data['resultados']);
    //exit;
    $output = array(
        "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
        "recordsTotal" => $total,
        "recordsFiltered" => count($resultados),
        "data" => $data,
    );

    echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: What are you trying to encode? `json_encode()` does not remove anything.

Comment: json_encode is perfect for converting arrays and objects to json-strings, but not for strings (html).

Comment: @miken32 i encode coluna1 (and other stuffs). Proprietarios/visualiza/some_code changes to proprietarios visualiza some_code

Comment: @Jeff i really need to send this HTML trought ajax to a datatable, it's a button that do some action.

Comment: `json_encode()` accepts a string, what is the string you're trying to pass to it? Edit your question to include this.

Comment: you can send it as simple string, but not as json, as it is no obejct/array. Just echo it.

Comment: after _edit_: just echo $output without json_encode

Comment: @Jeff i can't simply echo it because i'm using ajax with data table, wich requires me to send json_encode :(

Comment: Then you have to make `$caluna` an array or an object. Whatever datatable needs to get.

Comment: @Jeff but $output is an array...

Comment: Are you sure it's the json_encode that's the issue?  Try just `print_r` on `$output` - not as a solution but as a debugging test.  What does it give?  JSON encoding does affect slashes, but not remove them, it escapes them.  At least, if I define `$foo = array('https://www.example.com/foo/bar');` and then `echo json_encode($foo);` I get `["https:\/\/www.example.com\/foo\/bar"]` which then decodes correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON is not the best way to store strings or HTML. But, for some reason, enconding removes double slashes (eg. inserting in a database as a string).

Just try to add slashes:

```
addslashes(json_encode($array))
```